# collectionView function didSelectItemAt indexPath to pass data to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want my collectionView that's housed in AllWorkoutsVC to pass videoCode string data to the next viewController that's named VideoViewVC.

My collection view presents data correctly, however is the didSelectItemAt func i am having trouble with... this code runs fine and no warnings or errors are thrown, just that the variable myPassVideoCode not being passed to the target view controller

(i have removed some code for clarity..please ask for more if you feel is needed.)

collectionView class

```
class AllWorkoutsVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

      var myPassVideoCode = String()



     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "WorkoutsCell", for: indexPath) as? WorkoutsCell {
            let workout = workouts[indexPath.row]
            cell.updateViews(workout: workout)
            print("this is my workouts: " + workout.videoCode)
            return cell
        } else {
            return WorkoutsCell()
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let chosenWorkout = DataService.instance.getAllWorkouts()[indexPath.row] 
        myPassVideoCode = String(chosenWorkout.videoCode)
        print("this is my:  " + myPassVideoCode)//Note: this whole print does not appear in the console either
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "onPlayPressed2", sender: chosenWorkout)
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "onPlayPressed2" {
            let toNextVC = segue.destination as! VideoViewVC
            toNextVC.myPassVideoCode = myPassVideoCode
        }
    }

}
```

Target Class...

```
class VideoViewVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var myPassVideoCode = String()
    @IBOutlet var videoPlayer: YouTubePlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        videoPlayer.loadVideoID(myPassVideoCode)
    }
```

Comment: what the problem ????

Comment: the variable myPassVideoCode is nil when passed to the target view controller

Comment: in VideoViewVC declare it like this  var myPassVideoCode:String? ,,, also tried to print it inside didSelect ??

Comment: unfortunately no, i also have added 
print("this is my videoCode:  " + myPassVideoCode)
in didSelectItemAt function and this doesn't show in the results

Comment: @Sh_Khan with the  var myPassVideoCode:String? i get the error in VideoViewVC ...Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: show cellForRow

Comment: @Sh_Khan the cellForRow does print the videoCode also

Comment: may your model is nil print to verify

Comment: "this is my VideoViewVC video code: "

Comment: In `prepareForSegue`, print `toNextVC.myPassVideoCode` right after you assign it. This will help verify that at that point, your target actually holds it.

Comment: BTW, this `var myPassVideoCode = String()` cannot be nil. It's not declared as optional.

Comment: @bauerMusic i have added this print and it does not appear in the console at all

Comment: It could be printing an empty string. How's the print code looks like?

Comment: print("stored videoCode: \(myPassVideoCode)")

Comment: If it does not even prints "stored videoCode:", this block is probably not called.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're declaring a new local constant with the same name **myPassVideoCode** in:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt...
```

You only need to set **myPassVideoCode**. So change this line:

```
let myPassVideoCode = String(chosenWorkout.videoCode)
```

to:

```
myPassVideoCode = String(chosenWorkout.videoCode)
```

Comment: I have implemented this, the videoCode is still not being passed

Comment: I see your note saying that the print does not appear. What type is chosenWorkout.videoCode. Is it necessary to cast this? And if so is it not actually getting cast. You may need to handle this differently.

What does the print from this line look like: print("this is my workouts: " + workout.videoCode). If might be helpful if you could show us all of the related print info.

Comment: I have an array in DataService that contains all workouts, the workouts are as follows ...Workout(title: "Chest Press", videoCode: "_kAlQ5Bh5aY")... this videoCode needs to be passed into videoPlayer.loadVideoID(HERE) depending on which was selected in the collectionview. Also the print looks like this..... this is my workouts: 8zqv9dZvxB0?ecver=2   (this is repeated many times for each cell)

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question though. I'm assuming that the type of 'videoCode' is a String since you put it in quote in your last answer, is that correct? Also I find it much easier to use breakpoints instead of printing everything out because you can po things in the console and step through your code. Have you tried this?

Comment: sorry, yes videoCode is a string, i haven't i am not that familiar with breakpoints

Comment: Ok cool. I doubt this will change the outcome but since videoCode is a String you don't need to cast it when setting it to myPassVideoCode. With regards to breakpoints I'll point you to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html) as this is not the focus for this thread. I'll just add that in the Console—Command-Line Input/Output section you can print out things by first typing "po". For example: "po chosenWorkout.videoCode"

Comment: Could you print a few more things out and add all relevant print logs to your question. `print("chosen videoCode:  \(chosenWorkout.videoCode)")` before you set **myPassVideoCode** and `print("stored videoCode:  \(myPassVideoCode)")` before you set `toNextVC.myPassVideoCode = ...`

Comment: i have added these prints and they do not appear in the console at all

Comment: The entire print or just the variable? If the entire print isn't showing that suggests that that code is never getting executed.

Comment: the entire print which i dont understand

Comment: This is where breakpoints would come in handy although since you have a segue, do you see your segue performed?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Are you still running on sim or device? Are you running in Debug or Release?

Comment: no errors are appearing in the console and i am running this on a device, i am unsure wrt debug or release mode

Comment: Debug/Release is the 'Build Configuration' under the 'Info' tab of 'Edit Scheme'. But it sounds like you haven't changed it so you're most likely running in Debug which is what we want because we want the console to be more verbose.

Comment: So first and foremost code will only do what we tell it to do. The fact that you're not seeing some of the print statements in the log is a bit suspect. I'd really recommend reading through the documentation on breakpoints I linked and understanding how to use them to debug your code. Stepping through your code to see if it follows the path you expect and if everything is set to the correct values is incredibly helpful.

Comment: Apart from that you could add a print statement outside the if in the **prepare** for segue method. Since you said you see your segue executing then there's no reason this should not show in the console. If it's not showing then I'd question if some other transition is being executed instead of your custom segue.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new constant inside didSelectItemAt: 
`let myPassVideoCode = ...`

So you are not storing the value to the variable myPassVideoCode that you declared in the beginning of the class definition.

Comment: I have implemented this, the videoCode is still not being passed